# populate a jtable with json string results from a RESTful web service using java

Tags: java, json, swing, rest, jtable

I have a web service that returns JSON strings one by one based on query inputs, a GET request to the service returns this (there's only one entry in the database)

```
[{"checked":false,"dateposted":"2014-10-23T00:00:00","itemnumber":1,"quantity":5,"stockcheckid":1}]
```

at the moment I just have this `System.out.println` in a while loop.

what I want to do is be able to access these results in a way that I can input them into a jtable to display on a client application. I've read some guides about reading from JSON files etc but I cant find anything specific to REST web services. I hear GSON mentioned a lot, i tried that but i cant quite work out how to make it work in this context

I should also mention that the service can also send this data in XML format.

Do I somehow create a JSON file appending each new entry to it? and then populate the table from that file?

anyway here's the code that initiates the GET request.

```
public static void getRequest(String dataGet) {
  try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/nXXXXXXXXc/webresources/entities.stockchecks/" + dataGet);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

  }

}`
```

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418826/2587435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is a map.  You can serialise a JSON map to a Java map with Jackson like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JSONtoMap {

    public static final String json = "{\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\"}";

    public static class POJO{

        private Map<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, String> get() {
            return map;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void set(String name, String value) {
            map.put(name, value);
        }

    }

    @Test
    public final void test() throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper jsonmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        POJO p = jsonmapper.readValue(json, POJO.class);
        assertEquals(jsonmapper.writeValueAsString(p),json);    
    }

}
```

I imagine you could do something similar with GSON.  Another option is if you know the structure of the JSON object - in that case you make a simple POJO version and de-serialise into that instead of something like the POJO class I've defined above.

More detail and a similar version that supports [XML as well as JSON mapping](http://demeranville.com/deserialising-json-or-xml-to-a-map-using-java/)

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of how you obtain the data, use it to construct a suitable [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and use that model to construct the [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), the model accesses a `Map<String, String>` to fulfill the `TableModel` contract; you can substitute the `Map` obtained using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526435/230513). Because loading the data may take an indeterminate amount of time, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513).

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a combination of trashgod's and tom's answer, with an example, using Jackson and a TableModel. I really just want to give camickr's [**BeanTableModel/RowTableModel**](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) (which is a generic class to help us easily create table models to from pojos) a try (seems to work great).

For more information/details please see [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25418826/2587435)

`Entity` class (properties mapped to the keys in your json)

```
public class Entity {
    // field/property names must match to your json keys (with some exceptions)
    // other wise we are required to use further annotations
    private boolean checked;
    private Date dateposted;
    private int itemnumber;
    private int quantity;
    private int stockcheckid;

    /*** ----- DO NOT FORGET GETTERS AND SETTERS ---- ***/
}
```

Main class. Note the use `BeanTableModel`. You will need to download this class along with `RowTableModel` from the link above.

```
public class JsonTableDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "[{\"checked\":false,\"dateposted\":\"2014-10-23T00:00:00\",\"itemnumber\":1,\"quantity\":5,\"stockcheckid\":1}]";
        List<Entity> response = mapper.readValue(json, 
                TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(
                                              List.class, Entity.class));
        RowTableModel model = new BeanTableModel<>(Entity.class, response);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

---

Note, for long running task (many io task included), such as requesting a rest resource, you should use a `SwingWorker` as explained by trashgod. When the repsonse comes in, you can basically `addRow` to the `RowTableModel` instance. For instance if we use the same json response and model as above, we could simply do something like

```
response = mapper.readValue(json, 
        TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(
                                      List.class, Entity.class));
for (Entity entity : response) {
    model.addRow(entity);
}
```

---

### UPDATE

> I should also mention that the service can also send this data in XML format.

Looking at your json, it is an array of objects. With XML, the format is a little different, as you *must* have a root document element. So you can't just have say

```
<entity>
    <prop></prop>
</entity>
<entity>
    <prop></prop>
</entity>
```

It would need to be something like

```
<entities>
    <entity>
        <prop></prop>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <prop></prop>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

That being said, using data binding, the easiest way would be to create another class to wrap a `List<Entity>`. Now I'm not too familiar with Jackson's XML capabilities/features, but using JAXB, you can have a class like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entities {

    @XmlElement(name = "entity")
    protected List<Entity> entities;

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        if (entities == null) {
            entities = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }
}
```

Then you can unmarshal the below XMl into the `Entities` class. Here's an update demo to show both json and xml

```
public class JsonTableDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "[{\"checked\":false,\"dateposted\":\"2014-10-23T00:00:00\",\"itemnumber\":1,\"quantity\":5,\"stockcheckid\":1}]";
        List<Entity> response = mapper.readValue(json,
                TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(
                        List.class, Entity.class));
        RowTableModel jsonModel = new BeanTableModel<>(Entity.class, response);
        JTable jsonTable = new JTable(jsonModel) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };

        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                + "<entities>\n"
                + "    <entity>\n"
                + "        <checked>false</checked>\n"
                + "        <dateposted>2014-10-22T17:00:00-07:00</dateposted>\n"
                + "        <itemnumber>1</itemnumber>\n"
                + "        <quantity>5</quantity>\n"
                + "        <stockcheckid>1</stockcheckid>\n"
                + "    </entity>\n"
                + "</entities>";


        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entities.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Entities entities = (Entities)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        RowTableModel<Entity> xmlModel = new BeanTableModel<>(
                                         Entity.class, entities.getEntities());
        JTable xmlTable = new JTable(xmlModel){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JPanel jsonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jsonPanel.add(new JLabel("JSON Table", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        jsonPanel.add(new JScrollPane(jsonTable));
        panel.add(jsonPanel);

        JPanel xmlPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        xmlPanel.add(new JLabel("XML Table", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        xmlPanel.add(new JScrollPane(xmlTable));
        panel.add(xmlPanel);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(panel));
    }
}
```

[image]

- See more [about using JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#Introduction)