# JavaFX and JSON

Tags: json, javafx

Is it possible to process JSON with Java 7 or Java 8 without using 3rd party and without J2EE? I'd like to stick with JDK for a JavaFX desktop application. The only thing regarding JSON I've found so far is in J2EE. But even then it's very cirumstantial to use compared to libraries like gson. I had hopes that there's some implementation that uses JAXB to serialize into JSON instead of XML.

Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25458178/2587435). I haven't investigate it, but looks like something that may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you, I've already seen that. It requires EE. Doesn't work with SE.

Comment: You can always just grab the [json jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4), but as seen from the linked posted, POJO conversion looks a bit complicated. Jackson has good pojo mapping features, and also has [support for JAXB annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations). I don't think there is a solution that doesn't require some outside jars from the standard JDK.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use 3rd party then. Or stick with JAXB and XML. Thank you for your input.